# How to evaluate f strings using ast.literal_eval

Tags: python, string, python-3.6

When trying to evaluate f-strings with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) I get a `ValueError` about a "malformed node or string":

```
from ast import literal_eval

a = 10

literal_eval("f'test {a}'")
```

Throws the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<...> in <module>()
      3 a = 10
      4 
----> 5 literal_eval("f'test {a}'")

C:\...\lib\ast.py in literal_eval(node_or_string)
     83                     return left - right
     84         raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
---> 85     return _convert(node_or_string)
     86 
     87 

C:\...\lib\ast.py in _convert(node)
     82                 else:
     83                     return left - right
---> 84         raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
     85     return _convert(node_or_string)
     86 

ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.JoinedStr object at 0x000001F20CE718D0>
```

However it works without problems for raw or binary strings:

```
>>> literal_eval("r'This'")
'This'
>>> literal_eval("b'This'")
b'This'
```

Can I make `ast.literal_eval` work on f-strings? And if yes, what do I need to change?

Comment: `f'test {a}'` isn't a literal. It performs a calculation (the `FORMAT_VALUE` opcode).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't possible.  An f-string is sort of like the following<sup>1</sup> :

```
map = {}
map.update(globals())
map.update(locals())
string.format(**map)
```

This is actually a dramatic understatement -- f-strings also support other types of expressions that aren't just name-lookups or simple things like item access that you can get with vanilla format strings.  e.g. They support any other valid python expression including function calls, mathematical equations, etc.

```
>>> expr = '"boom"'
>>> f'foo{eval(expr)}'
'fooboom'
```

The f-string gets evaluated by using the `__format__` protocol and the expressions that it contains get evaluated using normal python.  This means that an f-string *can't* be a literal.  It's an expression<sup>1</sup>.  Note that like any arbitrary expression, it cannot be evaluated safely -- so you probably wouldn't even want it to be "eval-able" by `ast.literal_eval` anyway.

<sup><sup>1</sup>In the AST, you'll see that it is accomplished via the `JoinedStr`, `Str` and `FormattedValue` ast nodes.  Of these, the only one which could be considered a literal is `Str`.</sup>

Comment: Your code covers a common use of f strings (name interpolation), and is enough to explain the M's failure.  But it falls short of allowing the complex expressions that can occur between the braces, or between { and :. The actual equivalent is more like `process(string).format(<expresssion0>, <exression1>, ...)` where `process`pulls out the expressions so that they can be evaluated outside the simplified string.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy -- Yeah.  I had a footnote that was attempting to explain that f-strings are _more_ than just syntactic sugar for name lookups.  I don't think that I made that at all clear enough so I've tried to rework the text a bit to hopefully make it more clear ...

Comment: So, we can safely ignore `bandit` complaining? ref: https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blacklists/blacklist_calls.html#b307-eval

Answer (score 0):

F strings can contain arbitrarily complex expressions.  A simple example.

```
>>> a = 2; b=3; print(f'x{a**b}x')
```

x8x

They are neither literals or nor anything like literals and are not suitable for literal_eval.